# Pyomo: Setting variable branching priorities

Tags: pyomo

At Chapter 16 of [the documentation](http://www.pyomo.org/documentation/) the following is said:

> Exporting information to a solver or algorithm to aid in solving a mathematical program (e.g., warm-starting information, variable branching priorities).

Yet I cannot find an example of how variable priorities could be set (for compatable solvers). I cannot find something about this in the source code.

As setting variable priorities is solver-specific: with which solvers does this work? More specifically: how to do this with CPLEX or Gurobi? And may it also work for open-source solvers?

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible with the CPLEX LP solver using a fork of `pyomo`.

```py
m = ConcreteModel()
m.x = Var(domain=Integers)
m.s = RangeSet(10)
m.y = Var(m.s, domain=Integers)
m.o = Objective(expr=m.x + sum(m.y), sense=minimize)
m.c = Constraint(expr=m.x >= 1)
m.c2 = Constraint(expr=quicksum(m.y[i] for i in m.s) >= 10)

m.priority = Suffix(direction=Suffix.EXPORT, datatype=Suffix.INT)
m.direction = Suffix(direction=Suffix.EXPORT, datatype=Suffix.INT)  # this is optional

m.priority.set_value(m.x, 1)

m.priority.set_value(m.y, 2)
m.direction.set_value(m.y, BranchDirection.down)

m.direction.set_value(m.y[10], 1)

with SolverFactory('cplex', solver_io='lp') as opt:
    opt.solve(model, priorities=True)
```

You should now see something similar to this screenshot in the logs of your CPLEX run:

[image]

To run this currently you'll need to install a specific dev branch of pyomo as follows:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo.git@refs/pull/1300/merge
```

This should be made available to the `master` dev version of pyomo and eventually a pyomo release in due time.

Answer (score 0):

Pyomo has a system for passing options to the solvers. For the most part, these are passed exactly as specified, so you would look at the Gurobi or CPLEX documentation for what the accepted keywords and values are.

Comment: But how are these suffices passed to the solver? [In the solver source file, it appears that it is only possible to extract data from the solver, instead of to import it to the solver](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/CPLEX.py).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. The suffices are passed differently depending on which interface you are using behind the scenes. Pyomo is capable of using an *.lp file interface, an *.nl file interface, or for certain solvers, a direct python interface (among other options). For the AMPL Solver Library interface, you'll want to look at https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/repn/ampl_repn.py. For Gurobi direct, https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/GUROBI_RUN.py